# Send email from Linux server as html - Content type and html tags also visible in email

Tags: html, linux, shell, email

I am trying to send an email as html.

```
#!/bin/sh

#MAIL_LIST="gangadhar.n@xx.com"
MAIL_SENDER=foo

fnSendEmail(){
    echo ${BODY}| mail -r $MAIL_SENDER -s "$(echo "$MAIL_SUBJECT\nContent-Type: text/html")" "$MAIL_LIST"
}

MAIL_SUBJECT="Test email"

BODY="<html><body><div><h2>Hi All</h2><hr></div></body></html>";

fnSendEmail $BODY $MAIL_SENDER $MAIL_SUBJECT $MAIL_LIST
```

I am receiving email but html tags and Content type also visible in mails as below.

Subject as

```
"Test email\nContent-Type: text/html"
```

Email body as:

```
<html><body><div><h2>Hi All</h2><hr></div></body></html> NOTICE TO RECIPIENT:  If you are not the intended recipient of this e-mail, you are prohibited from sharing, copying, or otherwise using or disclosing its contents.  If you have received this e-mail in error, please notify the sender immediately by reply e-mail and permanently delete this e-mail and any attachments without reading, forwarding or saving them.  Thank you.
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using sendmail

```
#MAIL_LIST1="Gangadhar.N@xx.com"
MAIL_SENDER=dap

fnSendEmail(){
(
  echo To: $MAIL_LIST
  echo Cc: $MAIL_LIST
  echo From: dap53
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; "
  echo Subject: $MAIL_SUBJECT
  echo
  echo $BODY
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
}

MAIL_SUBJECT="Test email"
BODY="<html><body>Sample</body></html>"

fnSendEmail $BODY $MAIL_SENDER $MAIL_SUBJECT $MAIL_LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

Use option -a to append content-type header, -s is for subject, change your fnSendEmail to following it should work

```
fnSendEmail(){
    echo ${BODY}| mail -r $MAIL_SENDER -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "$(echo "$MAIL_SUBJECT\n")" "$MAIL_LIST"
}
```

Comment: Throwing --> Content-type: text/html: No such file or directory. Thank you for your reply. But I am still looking for right answer. Same code is working in different location. I am not sure why it is not working here.

Comment: Did you try small 'a' or capital 'A', small 'a' is to append a header and capital 'A' is to add attachment, I think you tried the capital A that is why getting No such file or directory, please try small 'a'.

Comment: It's small a. I just copied above code mentioned by you.