# Tabular format output through shell

Tags: bash, shell, email, html-email, email-attachments

I have the script output like below

```
dev1 FAIL
dev2 PASS
revion4 PASS
secor4 PASS
```

Now I need to send this output in a tabular format through mail. I tried below code:

```
input="file.txt"
tmpfile="tmpfile.html"

echo 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" ' > "$tmpfile"
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html><body><table border=1>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" >> "$tmpfile"
mail -s "test" abcd@domain.com < "$tmpfile"
```

Below is the output I am getting in my mail.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
<html><body><table border=1>
<tr>
<td>dev1</td>
<td>PASS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>dev2</td>
<td>PASS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>revision4</td>
<td>FAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sector6</td>
<td>PASS</td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Expected Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/47877581/9952196 helps.

Comment: agree with above comment. I always used `sendmail -t` for creating html emails. Good luck.

Comment: There must be an empty line between a mail header and mail body.